# Does the intrinsic energy of an object vary, if measured at different heights in a gravity field?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, gravity, mass, gravitational-redshift

The gravitational redshift has different interpretations. Several quantities vary with height (or seem to), by the same equation - time, energy, mass. I wondered if measurements can shed some light on this, though the difference is very small. The time rate is different at two different heights if you compare them, and careful measurements, involving elapsed time experiments, seem to show a real difference. But what about mass/energy. Intrinsic energy should vary with height, so mass should. Does the difference still exist if you go to a given height and measure the same object's mass there? Or does the mass depend on the viewpoint you consider it from, as in other situations, such as in SR. Can we (and have we) check(ed) how real the differences are by measurements?

Answer (score 0):

No, mass is an invariant quantity (both in SR and GR) and does not depend of the observer's frame of reference. Modern relativists have done away with the concept relativistic mass which did indeed depend on the velocity of the object.

However if we consider energy then it's measurement depends on the four velocity of the observer. More specifically if the body has a four momentum of $p^a$ and the observer has a four velocity of $u^a$ then the energy of the body as measured by the observer is given by (assuming $(-+++)$ signature)
$$E=-p_au^a$$
From the above expression we  can easily see that if we go into the rest frame of the body we obtain $E=mc^2$ where $m$ is the mass of the body.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I mentioned SR as an aside, the question was about intrinsic energy at different heights in a gravity field. Incidentally, it has been argued that if mass doesn't vary in SR,  the proportionality between weight and mass goes (which is even worse), because if heated the particle motion in the object leads to a slight increase in weight. But the question was about mass/energy, which varies with height in a gravity field, as a result of the gravitational redshift. This is part of well known basic physics, but is it measurable?

Comment: First of all mass and energy are different concepts. Mass is a Lorentz scalar whereas energy is not. Mass does NOT increase with height in a gravitational field. The energy measured depends on the frame of reference chosen. If intrinsic energy means the energy of the body measured in it's rest frame then we recover $E=mc^c$ so again no dependence on the position of the body in the gravitational field. So the question of the measurability of the variation in mass does not arise.

Comment: Typo above. It should read $E=mc^2$

Comment: So if we measure the same object at two different heights, both measurements local, it seems you're saying the mass will be the same at both heights, but the intrinsic energy will be different. And because of the gravitational redshift, the factor difference to the intrinsic energy will be sqrt (1 - [2GM/r[1]c^2])  /  sqrt (1 - [2GM/r[2]c^2]).

Comment: Perhaps someone could answer this question? Thank you. My most recent comment asks it more specifically.

Comment: I know this is late but the ratio you have given would be the ratio of the hypothetical energies as measured by an observer at infinity. This is not a measurable quantity as the product $-p^au_a$ can only be defined if both $p^a$ and $u^a$ lie in the same tangent space, which is obviously not true. Also can you define 'intrinsic energy'. I am not sure if we are talking about the same quantity.

Comment: Thank you. It's a simple question, I mean the object's internal rest energy, which far from any gravity fields is its rest mass by c^2. If the object is then placed near a mass such as the Earth, held at a given radius, does its mass change? Its internal energy changes - for one thing energy is linked to frequency, and in the gravitational redshift, quantities vary at different heights. It's thought they include the internal energy. So because of the mass-energy equivalence, it seems the mass also changes. Is it measurable, as relativistic mass arguably is via the weight increase when heated?

Comment: The objects internal rest energy will always be $mc^2$, $m$ being the rest mass. I think the confusion arises since gravitational redshift implies that there is a change in frequency measured which leads to the conclusion that the energy measured is different. However note that this energy measured is not the intrinsic/rest energy of the body which is an invariant. In this context the ratio that you mentioned above takes on a new meaning and becomes the ratio of energies of a falling body as measured by observers at a fixed radial coordinate.

Comment: In other words the ratio mentioned above is not the ratio of internal energies of the object since the observers are not in the rest frame of the object. Regarding it's measurability, this is indeed measurable. As to my 3rd comment where I said this could not be measured, is strictly speaking not true. It's because of the symmetries of the Schwarzschild spacetime that these different quantities turn out to be equal.

Comment: We know there is a different time rate at a different height in the field. This has been shown from elapsed time experiments. It means that the emitted frequency is different, say in the Pound Rebka experiment, it does not change en route. Are you saying this does not affect the object's internal rest energy? How do we know that - have any measurements been made?

Comment: The difference is time rates at different heights is a consequence of the different frames of reference of the measurement locations. The rest energy on the other hand is a scalar and couldn't care less about the rates at which times pass (apologies for the anthropomorphization) because in the body's own rest frame, time passes at the same rate  irrespective of where it is or what it's doing. In short, go into it's rest frame and measure it's energy. You will always get $mc^2$. Of course an obvious caveat is that all of these statements are only valid for test bodies.

Comment: Regarding experiments I am not aware of any explicit checks. It could perhaps be argued that the validity of GR indirectly implies that rest energy should be an invariant, but I am not sure.